# Compare two strings and display characters in both strings

Tags: haskell, count

I need a function that displays chars, who are on two given strings for the same volution.

Example:

checkChars “aabbcf” “aabce” => “ac”

What I got:

```
import Data.List 
import Data.Map
checkChars a b = nub $ intersect a b
    where
```

This basically intersects the two lists, but after the where I need code that counts the chars and filters it. Is this possible?

Comment: Counts which chars and filters which list using what predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea if this is what you want, but I assume you want something to output only the letters that occur the same number of times. This would do it:

```
checkChars a b = concatMap (take 1) $ intersect (group (sort a)) (group (sort b))
```

Comment: `nub` is overkill since identical characters are grouped together. Instead of `nub . concat` we can use `concatMap (take 1)`.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's true. This looks like some kind of homework question though, maybe shouldn't have answered, haha.